# How to select multiple rows in sql based on multiple min values of a column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following SQL query and the result of the query is shown below. How do i select multiple minimum values based on cnt column?

```
SELECT a.id , COUNT(a.id) cnt
from table1 a
where a.id in (SELECT id from table2 WHERE name = 'abc') 
GROUP BY a.id
```

Output of the above query

```
"id"    "cnt"
1003    3
1008    1
1011    2
1017    1
```

I would like the output to be

```
"id"    "cnt"
1008    1
1017    1
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can using having to check

```
SELECT a.id , COUNT(a.id) cnt
from table1 a
where a.id in (SELECT id from table2 WHERE name = 'abc') 
GROUP BY a.id
HAVING COUNT (a.id) =
    (SELECT MIN(cnt) FROM (SELECT a.id , COUNT(a.id) cnt
    from table1 a
    where a.id in (SELECT id from table2 WHERE name = 'abc') 
    GROUP BY a.id) as latest)
```

Check out this [db fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fG42Suqfyy1C5Qw8NMukih/0)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Having to get the Min count.

```
SELECT a.id , COUNT(a.id) cnt
FROM table1 a
WHERE a.id in (SELECT id from table2 WHERE name = 'abc') 
GROUP BY a.id
HAVING COUNT(id) = (SELECT MIN(cnt)                              
           FROM (SELECT COUNT(a.id) cnt
           FROM table1 a
           WHERE a.id in (SELECT id from table2 WHERE name = 'abc') 
           GROUP BY a.id) b);
```